# Htaccess - redirecting trailing slash to no-slash URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, trailing-slash

I need to redirect trailing slash exact URL ( [www.xyz.com/registration/](http://www.xyz.com/registration/) ) to non-slash ( [www.xyz.com/registration](http://www.xyz.com/registration) ) with httaccess.
But only this exact URL, not any other.
How to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do a 301 redirect to a specific URL:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/registration/$ /registration
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that this does not need `RewriteEngine On` (because `RedirectMatch` is not provided by mod_rewrite in the first place), this matches more than just the one specific URL wanted here. If the requested URL was `/registration/foobar`, then this would redirect to `/registrationfoobar`

Comment: And it would even match on `/foobar/registration/baz`, redirecting to `/foobar/registrationbaz`. This needs _anchoring_ of the pattern at the beginning and end. `RedirectMatch 301 ^/registration/$ /registration`

Comment: I know man, it was written on the go, and now is correct, before you posted the second comment.